# Проверка совпадения координат курсора и shape

Tags: c#

Есть 3 прямоугольника, у каждого есть координаты и id. Как мне сделать проверку, что я курсором навёлся на один из этих прямоугольников. Координаты прямоугольников в PointFloat типе, а курсора в point. Проверка идёт через foreach, так как прямоугольников может быть и 4,5,6 и n. Используется devExpress.

```
//Позиция мыши
ch = ((MouseEventArgs)e).Location;
//keyValue.Key - это KeyValuePair<DevExpress.Utils.PointFloat, string> keyValue здесь хранится информацию о позициях 
//прямоугольников и id
var sk = PointToControl(keyValue.Key); //Point
var sk1 = this.CalcHitItem(sk); //DiagramItem

var lb = PointToClient(ch); //PointFloat
var lb1 = this.CalcHitItem(lb); //DiagramItem

sk1 == lb1 - не работает, оно и понятно.
```

Comment: надо смотреть окрестность точки

Comment: [Rectangle.Contains](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.contains)

Answer (score 0):

Сравнивать надо разницу чтоб вернее было, а точность сами выбирайте

```
Math.Abs(a - b) < 0.1
```

sk1, lb1 - это DiagramItem его невозможно сложить или умножить и т.д. его можно сравнить только